# Tsumego problem 899

Tags: go, tsumego

I am not able to solve this tsumego problem 899 of the [elementary set](http://tsumego.tasuki.org/books/cho-1-elementary.pdf). Black is to move and perhaps to kill white. But it seems to me that regardless of what black does, white will always make one eye at the edge and the second eye below is clear, and these eyes cannot be cut from each other:

[image]

Comment: @Rainbolt the problem you linked is a completely different problem. So please undo the downvote. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: *"The problem you linked to is not the same problem I asked about; therefore, my question is not too narrow."* is a non sequitur. The downvote will remain. Sorry about the mismatched link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh sorry now I see:

[image]

Pretty tricky sequence :-)